# how to use javascript to consume an axis web service?

Tags: jquery, web-services

I am new to axis. I would like to consume an axis webserive using jquery. I set up a simple axis webservice (add method) and used the following code to send a soap message to it:

```
    var xmlMsg = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:q0=\"http://add.example.ws\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><soapenv:Body><q0:add><q0:a1>3.5</q0:a1><q0:a2>5.8</q0:a2></q0:add></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
    //var xmlMsg = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><ns1:add xmlns:ns1=\"urn:xmethods-add\"><a1>2.3</a1><a2>4.5</a2></ns1:add></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
    alert(xmlMsg);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        contentType:"text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"", 
        url:"http://localhost:8080/webServiceProj/services/AddService",  //http://localhost:8080/webServiceProj/services/AddService //http://127.0.0.1:8080/soap-proxy/soap/add/1.1 
        data:xmlMsg, 
        dataType:'xml',
        success: function(xml) { 
            if($.browser.msie){ 
                $("#result").append(xml.getElementsByTagName("ns1:out")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"<br/>"); 
            } 
            else{ 
                $(xml).find("out").each(function(){ 
                    $("#result").append($(this).text()+"<br/>"); 
                }) 
            } 
        }, 
        error: function(x, e) { 
            alert('error:'+x.responseText); 
        }, 
        complete: function(x) { 
            alert('complete:'+x.responseText); 
        } 
    });
```

But what I got from the response is that it is an error saying fault with SOAPAction. Can anyone give me some direction please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Axis web service?    Do you mean Ajax web service?

Comment: the web service i created used axis framework. As a matter of fact, it was automatically generated from eclipse. I would like to consume this web service in ajax way from a web page. There are a lot of examples using .net.

Answer (score 0):

This SOAP plugin for jQuery may help:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the SOAPAction header to the request, like the type and content type you already added.